# PUT API body missing in Postman / Insomnia

Tags: php, api, postman, put

I am sending API requests with applications like Postman and Insomnia.

I can send a POST request with a Body that is form-data, so that it looks like

```
parameters:[{"fullname" : "John Smith", "username" : "jsmith", "email" : "jsmith@example.com", "password" : "s348nfdf"},{"fullname" : "Janine Smith", "username" : "jsmith1", "email" : "jsmith1@example.com", "password" : "ddfgret567"}]↵
```

And everything works, I can get the parameters from the request in the backend.

However, if I change the request to PUT, the body (parameters above) is not in the request ($_REQUEST). The request itself is successful with no error codes.

I have also tried x-www-form-urlencoded and raw JSON.

Why is the body (parameters) missing?

Comment: As per the docs, $_REQUEST only contains items from GET, POST and COOKIE. If yo uwant the body of PUT, use `php://input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no body in `$_REQUEST[]`. Use:

`$body = file_get_contents('php://input');`

From the [PHP manual entry on I/O](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) streamsdocs:

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".